# Python OpenSSL - Verifying a CRL File

Tags: python, openssl

We are using Python & OpenSSL to read a CRL file to extract the list of revoked certficate Serial Numbers.  We need to add a check to verify that the CRL has been exported with a trusted certificate before we parse the file.

From the command line the appropriate OpenSSL command is:
`openssl crl -inform DER -in {crlfile} -CAfile {mycacert} -noout`

which outputs either `verify OK` or `verify failure`

Is there a Pythonic way to perform this verification rather than having to shell out to a command line script?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to do this using python is to use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

If you are using later than Python 2.7 you can then call the [check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) method, with the command you want to run. See below:

```
import subprocess

# Files to verify
crlfile = r"path\to\crlfile"
mycacert = r"path\to\mycacert"
# Set up args
args = ["openssl", "crl", "-inform", "DER", "-in", crlfile, "-CAfile", mycacert, "-noout"]
# Run the thing
output = subprocess.check_output(args)
verified = True if output.upper() == "VERIFY OK" else False
```

As per [this](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/pull/483) pull request this functionality appears to now be available in [pyOpenSSL](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl).

Comment: Thanks, Noelkid but it's not quite the solution that I am looking for.

The CRL is already contained in a String buffer within Python and we don't particularly want to go via the file system if at all possible so we are ideally looking to invoke it directly from python rather than wrapping a native call.

Comment: I got the feeling this wasn't what you wanted, will have a further look into it.

Comment: Hi Noelkd, even though your answer wasn't exactly what I was originally looking for I have not found a better solution and so I have implemented & accepted your answer.

Comment: I ended up looking into [pyOpenSSL](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl) couldn't see the functionality you required `out of the box`. If anyone else has a better answer you can always award the question to them later!

Answer (score 3):

There is a more Pythonic way to do that, by using pyOpenSSL:

```
import requests
import OpenSSL

# Donwload and load your CRL
resp = requests.get(CRL_URL)
crl = OpenSSL.crypto.load_crl(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, resp.content)

# Export CRL as a cryptography CRL.
crl_crypto = crl.to_cryptography()

# Load CA CERTIFICATE
ca = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, '-----BEGIN...'.encode())    

# Get CA Public Key as _RSAPublicKey
ca_pub_key = ca.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key()

# Validate CRL against CA
valid_signature = crl_crypto.is_signature_valid()
```